# How to test whether particular action was called in componentDidMount?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, mocha.js, sinon

I am using Redux in my project, for testing the stack is Mocha, Chai, and Sinon. In a particular Container Component **ABC**'s componentDidMount an action **xyz** is dispatched. In the unit test for **ABC** I want to check whether **xyz** was called. The code for **ABC**

```
import {xyz} from 'action';
class ABC extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount(){
   // some other magic
   this.props.xyz();
   }
   render(){
   // return html
   }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
       return bindActionCreators({xyz});  
 } 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ABC)
```

The unit test to check whether **xyz** is called from componentDidMount which fails

```
import {xyz} from 'path to xyz action';
import {ABC} from 'path to ABC';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
describe('ABC', function () {
     it('renders correctly', function () {
           let store = {} // fake store object
           let actionSpy = sinon.spy(xyz);
           let wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}
              <ABC/>
            </Provider>);
           actionSpy.should.have.callCount(1);
    });
});
```

The action **xyz** is called when the test run is confirmed via log messages. The failure message is **AssertionError: expected spy to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given that you're importing the unwrapped version of your component, you are not passing any props in at all (the store is not injecting props into your component). Therefore, you should be passing that spy to your component:

```
mount(<ABC xyz={actionSpy} />);
```

Should work after that!

Comment: I've tried this it doesn't work, and I'm not importing the unwrapped version of the component.

Comment: I see, then you are importing nothing because you have `import {ABC} from 'path to ABC';` which is a named import. If you were to export the unwrapped component then you might have better luck. It's a good pattern for testing redux components anyhow. It's possible that you're importing the wrapped component and the store is overriding the prop you're passing.

Comment: How can I do it for the wrapped component?

Comment: Short answer? You can't. The wrapped component is going to pass the bound action creator directly, meaning you can't put a spy on there.